# External Hard drive doesn't show up anywhere

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have already checked Device Manager and Disk Management already so please don't suggest those two. My problem right now is that my WD My Passport stopped being recognized one day out of the blue. It seems the drive is recognized in Device Manager as WD SES Device but without drivers, I have already installed the drivers with multiple methods over 10 times on 2 different computers, I've tried different ports and different operating systems. The thing I can think of now is that the physical disk is bad, but that wouldn't make sense as the Disk Drive driver also shows inside the Device Manager, it also shows when I use a tool to read PCI ports. Is there anything I haven't tried that someone could suggest to me?

Comment: check disk management again and look see if any say foreign disk you will need to scroll down the list below the list with letters, otherwise could be fault disk or usb or nto enough power

Comment: Thats not the case I've already checked that bought a new usb cord

Comment: you have checked if it a fault disk? and by usb i mean the usb cable and the usb connection

Comment: I don't know what you mean by faulty disk not sure how I would check that but I bought a new usb cable and yes the computer can see it but not in disk management or explorer

Comment: fault disk means the hard disk is failing in some form, how do you see it on the computer if not through disk management or explorer?

Comment: Said in the post, it doesnt appear at all but the computer knows its there

Comment: I am asking you to explain how the computer knows it is there

Comment: I used a program that allows you to see what is connected to your USB ports, a PCI detector I think it was called, can't remember the name though

Comment: just because it can see it connected to the usb port doesn't mean it can read it..., i suggest looking at the hard disk itself , i honestly think the drive is dying